# Best way to migrate huge sqlite databases in Etherpad Lite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, etherpad

I run Etherpad Lite since two years with sqlite. Now I will migrate the database to MySQL or Redis. I used the `bin/migrateDirtyDBtoMySQL.js` as inspiration to write my own little migration script. Here it is:

```
require("ep_etherpad-lite/node_modules/npm").load({}, function(er,npm) {

    process.chdir(npm.root+'/..');

    var settings = require("ep_etherpad-lite/node/utils/Settings");
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
    var sqliteDb = new sqlite3.Database('var/sqlite.db');
    var db = require("ep_etherpad-lite/node/db/DB");

    db.init(function() {
        db = db.db;

        sqliteDb.each("SELECT * FROM store", function(err, row) {
            db.set(row.key,row.value);
        });
    });

});
```

After sqlite3 dependency is installed it works **but** my sqlite.db file is over 700 MB and the call:

```
node migrateSqliteDBtoEtherpad.js
```

terminated with kill signal. How can i handle such huge databases with nodejs and etherpad-lite?

Answer (score 0):

One solution with PHP to migrate the data to redis:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$db = new PDO('sqlite:sqlite.db');
$redis = new Predis\Client();

foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM store") as $row) {
    $redis->set($row['key'], $row['value']);
}
```

You must install Predis via composer in this example.